# Post to Friends Wall and un-authorize error

Tags: ios

I am trying to post to friend wall and it wouldn't work. I can post to my wall though.

```
     - (void)publishStory
{
    NSString *graph=@"me/feed";
    if([self.friendId length]!=0){
        graph=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed", self.friendId];
    }
    self.postParams = [@{
                       @"link" : self.link,
                       @"picture" : self.imageUrl,
                       @"name" :self.name,
                       @"caption" :self.caption,
                       @"description" : self.postMessageTextView.text
                       } mutableCopy];


    [FBRequestConnection
     startWithGraphPath:graph
     parameters:self.postParams
     HTTPMethod:@"POST"
     completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                         id result,
                         NSError *error) {
         NSString *alertText;
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Error publish %@", error.localizedDescription);
             alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                          @"error: domain = %@, code = %d",
                          error.domain, error.code];
         } else {
             alertText = @"Posted to Facebook. Thank you";
         }
         // Show the result in an alert
         [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Result"
                                     message:alertText
                                    delegate:self
                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!"
                           otherButtonTitles:nil]
          show];
     }];


}
```

This is the error.

```
body =         {
        error =             {
            code = 200;
            message = "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 403;
```

Comment: Do you have the access token?

Comment: Have you add access perimeters for post on friends wall. for example for photo access permission is "user_photos".

Comment: you are using very old method of Facebook. try to use New Facebook SDK http://developers.facebook.com/ios/ and i think at firstime login time you are not set permission for friend's wall-post